# Missing 3 recources for the Slick carousel. How do I implement those?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

In the [console](https://ibb.co/3NKG8mS) it says that I'm missing the slick.woff, ajax-loader.gif and slick.tff.

So I've found the CDN links for all these 3, but I have no idea how to implement them in my code (or in what kind of tag).

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/ajax-loader.gif

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/fonts/slick.ttf

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/fonts/slick.woff

Comment: How are you installing slick itself? I.e. its main JS and CSS files... Those three files you linked are relative imports from `slick.css` so it may depend how you are including that file in your project.

Comment: For the JS I use these two:<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"> </script>    

 <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>                                                   
                                                                                                                        
 And for CSS: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>

Answer (score 0):

The resources you've mentioned that are failing to load are referenced as relative imports in Slick's stylesheets.

Make sure that you've included these stylesheets (the first code block below) correctly, [as per the Slick documentation:](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick#example-using-jsdelivr)

> #### Example using jsDelivr
>
> Just add a link to the css file in your `<head>`:
>
> ```
> <!-- Add the slick-theme.css if you want default styling -->
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
> <!-- Add the slick-theme.css if you want default styling -->
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
> ```
>
> Then, before your closing  tag add:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
> ```